# Enable and disable Highcharts tooltip with drill menu

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am currently working on something that disables the tooltip when I click on a point in a series by using the `click()` event.

Here’s a screenshot of the tooltip BEFORE clicking on the point:

[image]

Here’s a crude example that kind of demonstrates what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/8dyegL2f/1/

I replaced the drill menu code (I couldn’t find a way to emulate it in Fiddle) with some pseudocode. Here’s an attached screenshot of the disabled tooltip AFTER click on the point, which shows the drill menu:

[image]

When I click on the point, this opens the drill menu. When the drill menu is open, this disables the tooltip at the same time so they don’t overlap as demonstrated from my code.

Here comes the problem - because the drill menu takes focus AWAY from the chart, when I click outside of the drill menu, this closes the drill menu, but because I am out of focus of the chart, the .click() event won’t register, and I cannot re-enable the tooltip.

So my question is - is there a way to have the click event register despite having the drill menu open, so I can set the tooltip.enable back to true?

A hack I did was to use the `mouseOver` event to re-enable the tooltip when the drill menu gets closed, but that would break mobile compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve what I wanted simply with changing the hide delay to 0 in my series options:

```
hideDelay: 0
```